# Elasticsearch allocates primary shards only on first node in the cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 5 node elasticsearch cluster to store logs ( 4 master eligble and data and 1 master only node)
and all primary shards that was created allocate only on firt node in the cluster so the 1st node almost totally overloaded by cpu
why this happens? nodes have the same specs (cpu,ram,etc)

here is my cat/allocation ( i manually move shards from elastic-01 every morning, and on elastic-01 is fewer shards that on the others, but anyway load on elastic-01 is big)

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host        ip          node
   354        4.9tb     4.9tb    804.7gb      5.7tb           86 10.0.5.22 10.0.5.252 elastic-01
   435          4tb       4tb      1.7tb      5.7tb           70 10.0.5.23 10.0.5.23 elastic-02
   434        4.6tb     4.6tb        1tb      5.7tb           80 10.0.5.27 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
   434        4.7tb     4.7tb   1014.8gb      5.7tb           82 10.0.5.28 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
```

and here is nodeattrs

```
node       host         ip           attr              value
elastic-07 10.0.5.28  10.0.5.28  ml.machine_memory 42002579456
elastic-07 10.0.5.28  10.0.5.28  ml.max_open_jobs  512
elastic-07 10.0.5.28  10.0.5.28  xpack.installed   true
elastic-07 10.0.5.28  10.0.5.28  ml.max_jvm_size   27917287424
elastic-07 10.0.5.28  10.0.5.28  zone              zone2
elastic-07 10.0.5.28  10.0.5.28  transform.node    true
elastic-01 10.0.5.22  10.0.5.22  ml.machine_memory 42002583552
elastic-01 10.0.5.22  10.0.5.22  ml.max_open_jobs  512
elastic-01 10.0.5.22  10.0.5.22  xpack.installed   true
elastic-01 10.0.5.22  10.0.5.22  ml.max_jvm_size   27917287424
elastic-01 10.0.5.22  10.0.5.22  zone              zone1
elastic-01 10.0.5.22  10.0.5.22  transform.node    true
elastic-02 10.0.5.23  10.0.5.23  ml.machine_memory 42407346176
elastic-02 10.0.5.23  10.0.5.23  ml.max_open_jobs  512
elastic-02 10.0.5.23  10.0.5.23  xpack.installed   true
elastic-02 10.0.5.23  10.0.5.23  ml.max_jvm_size   27917287424
elastic-02 10.0.5.23  10.0.5.23  zone              zone1
elastic-02 10.0.5.23  10.0.5.23  transform.node    true
elastic-06 10.0.5.27  10.0.5.27  ml.machine_memory 42002579456
elastic-06 10.0.5.27  10.0.5.27  ml.max_open_jobs  512
elastic-06 10.0.5.27  10.0.5.27  xpack.installed   true
elastic-06 10.0.5.27  10.0.5.27  ml.max_jvm_size   27917287424
elastic-06 10.0.5.27  10.0.5.27  zone              zone2
elastic-06 10.0.5.217  10.0.5.27  transform.node    true
elastic-11 10.0.25.24 10.0.25.24 ml.machine_memory 12428124160
elastic-11 10.0.25.24 10.0.25.24 ml.max_open_jobs  512
elastic-11 10.0.25.24 10.0.25.24 xpack.installed   true
elastic-11 10.0.25.24 10.0.25.24 ml.max_jvm_size   2147483648
elastic-11 10.0.25.24 10.0.25.24 zone              zone3
elastic-11 10.0.25.24 10.0.25.24 transform.node    false
```

here is output from GET ilm/policy

```
{".alerts-ilm-policy":{"version":19,"modified_date":"2022-08-23T04:29:09.081Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_primary_shard_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},".deprecation-indexing-ilm-policy":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T18:09:22.265Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_primary_shard_size":"10gb","max_age":"14d"}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.04.06-000007",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.03.09-000005",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.02.09-000003",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.02.23-000004",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.06.29-000013",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.07.13-000014",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.08.10-000016",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.07.27-000015",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.01.26-000002",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.08.24-000017",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.01.12-000001",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.06.15-000012",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.04.20-000008",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.05.04-000009",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.03.23-000006",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.06.01-000011",".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.05.18-000010"],"data_streams":[".logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default"],"composable_templates":[".deprecation-indexing-template"]}},".fleet-actions-results-ilm-policy":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T17:12:45.443Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"300gb","max_age":"30d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"90d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},".items-forteforex":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-07-22T05:20:41.438Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"50gb"}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[".items–000001"],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},".lists":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-07-22T05:20:41.356Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"50gb"}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[".lists-forteforex-000001"],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},"180-days-default":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T18:09:22.121Z","policy":{"phases":{"warm":{"min_age":"2d","actions":{"forcemerge":{"max_num_segments":1},"shrink":{"number_of_shards":1}}},"cold":{"min_age":"30d","actions":{}},"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_primary_shard_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"180d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}}},"_meta":{"description":"built-in ILM policy using the hot, warm, and cold phases with a retention of 180 days","managed":true}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},"30-days-default":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T18:09:22.229Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_primary_shard_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"30d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}},"warm":{"min_age":"2d","actions":{"forcemerge":{"max_num_segments":1},"shrink":{"number_of_shards":1}}}},"_meta":{"description":"built-in ILM policy using the hot and warm phases with a retention of 30 days","managed":true}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},"365-days-default":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T18:09:21.893Z","policy":{"phases":{"warm":{"min_age":"2d","actions":{"forcemerge":{"max_num_segments":1},"shrink":{"number_of_shards":1}}},"cold":{"min_age":"30d","actions":{}},"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_primary_shard_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"365d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}}},"_meta":{"description":"built-in ILM policy using the hot, warm, and cold phases with a retention of 365 days","managed":true}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},"7-days-default":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T18:09:22.046Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_primary_shard_size":"50gb","max_age":"7d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"7d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}},"warm":{"min_age":"2d","actions":{"forcemerge":{"max_num_segments":1},"shrink":{"number_of_shards":1}}}},"_meta":{"description":"built-in ILM policy using the hot and warm phases with a retention of 7 days","managed":true}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},"90-days-default":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T18:09:22.192Z","policy":{"phases":{"warm":{"min_age":"2d","actions":{"forcemerge":{"max_num_segments":1},"shrink":{"number_of_shards":1}}},"cold":{"min_age":"30d","actions":{}},"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_primary_shard_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"90d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}}},"_meta":{"description":"built-in ILM policy using the hot, warm, and cold phases with a retention of 90 days","managed":true}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},"ilm-history-ilm-policy":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2021-04-16T05:52:27.071Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"90d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":["ilm-history-2-000017","ilm-history-2-000016","ilm-history-2-000015","ilm-history-2-000014",".ds-ilm-history-5-2022.07.11-000010",".ds-ilm-history-5-2022.06.11-000008",".ds-ilm-history-5-2022.05.12-000006",".ds-ilm-history-5-2022.08.10-000012"],"data_streams":["ilm-history-5"],"composable_templates":["ilm-history"]}},"kibana-event-log-policy":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2021-04-23T06:56:32.286Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"90d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[".kibana-event-log-7.16.2-000005",".kibana-event-log-7.16.2-000007",".kibana-event-log-7.16.2-000006",".kibana-event-log-7.16.2-000008"],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[".kibana-event-log-7.16.2-template"]}},"kibana-reporting":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T18:12:47.764Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[".reporting-2022-08-07",".reporting-2022-06-05",".reporting-2022-08-28",".reporting-2022-05-29",".reporting-2022-03-27",".reporting-2022-05-08",".reporting-2022-01-16",".reporting-2022-08-21",".reporting-2022-01-23",".reporting-2022-09-04",".reporting-2022-05-22"],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[]}},"logs":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2021-04-16T05:52:26.933Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":["logs"]}},"metrics":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2021-04-16T05:52:26.979Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":["metrics"]}},"ml-size-based-ilm-policy":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2021-04-16T05:52:26.877Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"50gb"}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[".ml-state",".ml-stats"]}},"slm-history-ilm-policy":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2021-04-16T05:52:27.112Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}},"delete":{"min_age":"90d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[".slm-history-2-000014",".slm-history-2-000015",".slm-history-2-000016",".slm-history-2-000017"],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[".slm-history"]}},"synthetics":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2022-01-12T18:09:21.976Z","policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"min_age":"0ms","actions":{"rollover":{"max_primary_shard_size":"50gb","max_age":"30d"}}}},"_meta":{"description":"default policy for the synthetics index template installed by x-pack","managed":true}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":["synthetics"]}},"watch-history-ilm-policy":{"version":1,"modified_date":"2021-04-16T05:52:27.024Z","policy":{"phases":{"delete":{"min_age":"7d","actions":{"delete":{"delete_searchable_snapshot":true}}}}},"in_use_by":{"indices":[],"data_streams":[],"composable_templates":[".watch-history-13"]}}}
```

nothing criminal, right?
and yeah, i have 50 indices with docs.deleted and at the moment i do force_merge 1 by one of this indices

for example this is shards that created in 03.09.2022

```
cat teks
lile-abz-2022.09.03                                           0     r      STARTED   1818053  565.8mb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
lile-abz-2022.09.03                                           0     p      STARTED   1818053  545.6mb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
pari-kurma-market-a-2022.09.03                                0     r      STARTED   9258217    5.7gb 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
pari-kurma-market-a-2022.09.03                                0     p      STARTED   9258217    5.7gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
gavn-pyati-2022.09.03                                         0     r      STARTED  33761356   14.7gb 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
gavn-pyati-2022.09.03                                         0     p      STARTED  33761356   14.8gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
gavn-pyati-3-2022.09.03                                       0     r      STARTED   9768830    3.9gb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
gavn-pyati-3-2022.09.03                                       0     p      STARTED   9768830    3.9gb 10.0.5.23 elastic-02
lola-chik-a-2022.09.03                                        0     r      STARTED   9581756    3.2gb 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
lola-chik-a-2022.09.03                                        0     p      STARTED   9581756    3.2gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
lila-xyu-a-2022.09.03                                         0     r      STARTED   1441592  605.5mb 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
lila-xyu-a-2022.09.03                                         0     p      STARTED   1441592  603.3mb 10.0.5.23 elastic-02
gavn-pyati-1-2022.09.03                                       0     r      STARTED  10179423    3.9gb 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
gavn-pyati-1-2022.09.03                                       0     p      STARTED  10179423    3.9gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
gorilla-energ-a-2022.09.03                                    0     r      STARTED  19341369   26.6gb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
gorilla-energ-a-2022.09.03                                    0     p      STARTED  19341369   26.4gb 10.0.5.23 elastic-02
chih-bimochk-a-2022.09.03                                     1     r      STARTED  23188624   22.5gb 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
chih-bimochk-a-2022.09.03                                     1     p      STARTED  23188624   22.4gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
chih-bimochk-a-2022.09.03                                     2     r      STARTED  23181295   22.5gb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
chih-bimochk-a-2022.09.03                                     2     p      STARTED  23181295   22.4gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
chih-bimochk-a-2022.09.03                                     3     r      STARTED  23175665   22.5gb 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
chih-bimochk-a-2022.09.03                                     3     p      STARTED  23175665   22.4gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
chih-bimochk-a-2022.09.03                                     0     r      STARTED  23182594   22.5gb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
chih-bimochk-a-2022.09.03                                     0     p      STARTED  23182594   22.4gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
prod-ca-a-2022.09.03                                          0     r      STARTED  97339290   16.8gb 10.0.5.27 elastic-06
prod-ca-a-2022.09.03                                          0     p      STARTED  97339290   16.8gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
jerusal-abracatd-a-2022.09.03                                 0     r      STARTED   3647629    7.6gb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
jerusal-abracatd-a-2022.09.03                                 0     p      STARTED   3647629    7.6gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
prod-anstasia-a-2022.09.03                                    0     r      STARTED  42794060   14.9gb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
prod-anstasia-a-2022.09.03                                    0     p      STARTED  42794060   14.9gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
sasha-log-2022.09.03                                          0     r      STARTED     67602    6.5mb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
sasha-log-2022.09.03                                          0     p      STARTED     67602    6.5mb 10.0.5.23 elastic-02
prod-adedimitrious-a-2022.09.03                               0     r      STARTED  10874246   22.4gb 10.0.5.28 elastic-07
prod-adedimitrious-a-2022.09.03                               0     p      STARTED  10874246   22.4gb 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
```

as you can see almost all primaries located in elatic-01 with highest disk utiization, but nor on elastic-02 or other nodes

ADDED

i'm just create a index with 5 primary and 0 replicas and all of the primaries was allocated on elastic-01

```
curl -s  -X GET   http://10.0.5.22:9200/_cat/shards?v | grep swiss
i_want_swiss_passport                                         4     p      STARTED         0     226b 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
i_want_swiss_passport                                         1     p      STARTED         0     226b 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
i_want_swiss_passport                                         2     p      STARTED         0     226b 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
i_want_swiss_passport                                         3     p      STARTED         0     226b 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
i_want_swiss_passport                                         0     p      STARTED         0     226b 10.0.5.22 elastic-01
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the results you get from `GET _cat/allocation?v` and `GET _cat/nodeattrs?v` ? Depending on the results, I'll ask you more.

Comment: @Val added to question, thanks!

Comment: Thanks but can you provide answers to the questions I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73554096/elasticsearch-disk-usage-issue) regarding ILM and deleted documents.

Comment: @Val added to question! thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: As we've seen in your [preview question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73554096/elasticsearch-disk-usage-issue), elastic-01 is at 86% disk utilization, which means that no shards will get assigned to it anymore. It would help to know to which index/es those big 100GB+ shards belong to. Can you show the relevant output from _cat/shards that shows those index names, so we can investigate further?

Comment: Also why do you say that "all primary shards that was created allocate only on first node in the cluster"? We can see that the shards are properly balanced over all nodes, except for elastic-01 for the reason mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @Val yeah, but even disk utilization is high on elastic-01, anyway all primary shards every day created only on elastic-01

Comment: I don't think so, it's not possible that elastic-01 is getting any shard, all shards are getting assigned to 02, 06 and 07 and the latter two are also close to 85% disk utilization, so you'll soon have only 02 which will get new shards and that will create more imbalance

Comment: @Val added shards output in post, yeah this is freaking strange but everyday all new primary shards created almost only at elastic-01

Comment: I would like to see all indices having shards allocated on elastic-01, so the same as what you did with `_cat/shards | grep "elastic-01"` but with all fields visible. You might want to [gist](https://gist.github.com/) the output as it will be quite big

Comment: @Val i add a snippet to the answer

Comment: I would like to see the actual big shards you currently have on elastic-01, not new ones you're creating.

Comment: @Val dear Val the shards on elastic-01 is here https://gist.github.com/tabbi/b2fc675bedebb680d52318c826d81bfa

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind adding `?bytes=b` to your _cat/shards call so we have numerical byte values?

Comment: @Val here is https://gist.github.com/tabbi/0402afa67b449a233eabddb232b88024

Comment: Thanks but we're still seeing "human" sizes in gb/mb and not raw bytes sizes

Comment: @Val sorry, update this gist

Comment: @Val sorry, what do you think about it?

Comment: This is weird, can you show the results of `GET _cat/allocation` again please?

Comment: @Val solved by delete almost all indices, I think that this happened because in some strange way large shards hit the first node, but there were fewer of them than on the rest of the nodes in the cluster, so the elastic created new shards on the first node

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't explain how you landed in the situation. Let us know if that happens again.